# "das geht leider nicht" - which noun is the "das" here an Artikel for?

Tags: article, demonstrative-pronoun

I am just learning to speak German, and I came across the aforementioned sentence. To my understanding, we use articles der, die das for nouns, but it seems like in

Question :

> Gehen wir ins Kino am Samstag?

> Das geht leider nicht.

does not have any nouns, so what is the das for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does not have any nouns

Such sentence never appears out of context (usually a question, but not necessarily).

> so what is the das for?

*Das* refers to the verb and noun introduced in the question before (*in[da]s Kino gehen*).

It's merely the same as in English you say:

> > Would you want to go to the cinema with me at saturday?

> > **That**'s unfortunately not possible.

Check @amadeusamadeus [answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/59342/28897) for the exact grammatical definition (*Demonstrativpronomen*).

Comment: but in the answe there is no noun, merely a verb. It almost seems as if the article is for the verb gehen?

Comment: @user1234 As mentioned it refers to the verb and the noun: _ins Kino gehen_.

Comment: "Such sentence never appears out of context" Yeah no, it does, if the context may be merely implied. Sometimes it may be ambiguous, like *es* as well, or determinative. "Das kann doch nicht wahr sein [dass das das, das da das dass allein ersetzen könnte, es doch nicht tut". Es ist kaum konkreter als *Da*. So könnte *das's doch was faul* oder *da's* auch also deiktisch sein und eventual genitive "dessen ist was nicht richtig, *des* geht dir nix an", wie pseudo dativ in "dem ist nicht so"

Comment: Reading the first word, "does", has me wonderbifbthere was some confusion. "Does kann man nicht erklären"; oder "Das he understand" (this he understand)?

Comment: @vectory Hmm well. At least the context with all your (counter-)examples seems to be implied. E.g. you spot some long not seen person at the street and say _Das darf doch nicht wahr sein._ implies _, dass ich Dich hier nach Jahren wieder treffe_.

Answer (score 10):

In this sentence, ***das* is not an article, but a demonstrative pronoun** (*Demonstrativpronomen*). It refers to the verbal phrase *ins Kino gehen*.

While *diese[r,s]* ('this') and *jene[r,s]* ('that') usually refer to real things and are somewhat emphasizing, *der/die/das* often refer to things from speech and are less emphasizing. There is no complete English equivalent, however it matches closely French *cela*/*ça* and Italian *ciò*, for example.

*Der* and *die* can also be used as demonstrative pronouns for nouns with the respective gender. Verbal phrases, however, are always refered to by neuter *das*.