# Gender of a noun in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, gender, demonstrative-pronoun

I have encountered a sentence in our A1 book as:

*Haben Sie schon mal eine Radtour gemacht?* then, another person answers that: *Ja, das habe ich schon gemacht.*

However, we know that *Tour* is feminine, and its article should be *die* not *das*. Thus, my question is: Does the above sentence have a correct structure?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59340

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Thanks for this interesting link.

Comment: In addition to Ardoris great answer: The authors of the book should add “Ja, ich habe schon mal eine gemacht.” as a typical answer to the question “Haben Sie schon mal eine Radtour gemacht?” That's a more natural way - for the German ear - to answer the question than “Das habe ich schon gemacht”, although the latter is technically correct, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes.

Indeed, the word [*Tour*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tour) is feminine. So, it's correct to say something like *Die Tour war lang.* The *die* would be the word's article.
It's valid to use *die* in this case as person B. However, this means one very specific bike tour. Using *die* would be

> *Yes, I did this tour*

in English. But person A asks about bike tours in general (which is also underlined by the *schon mal*).
Person A in English:

> *Have you ever made a bike tour?*

The person B in your example uses *das*. Person B refers to the action of doing a bike tour in general, not one specific tour. Person B could also answer:

> *Ja, ich habe schon [mal] eine Radtour gemacht.*

Normally, one inserts *mal* almost always, especially in this construction.

The point here is that it's undefined which tour is meant. The article *eine* is the point. If person B said

> *Ja, ich habe schon [mal] die(se) Radtour gemacht.*

then it would be clear. However, the *das* refers to the "generic action" of doing a bike tour (something like *eine Radtour machen*).
The *das* of person B in your question is a demonstrative pronoun ([Demonstrativpronomen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrativpronomen)).

**Edit:** Thanks for clarification [@amadeusamadeus](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/39389/amadeusamadeus); see the answer to ["das geht leider nicht" - which noun is the "das" here an Artikel for?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/59340).

Comment: *Das* is a demonstrative pronoun that refers to the verbal phrase *eine Radtour machen*. See the question I linked in the comments of this questions for more details on this.

Comment: Many thanks for your elaborate answer.